# Has Bran already been to the past?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

**Spoilers - Don't read if you have not seen episode 5 season 6 of *Game of Thrones*.**

> In Episode 5 of season 6 Game of Thrones Bran was in the past and while in the past he warged into Hodor in the present which made a connection between present Hodor and past Hodor hence making Hodor "Hodor".

My question is that Hodor was Hodor from since Season 1 so does that mean Bran had already been to the past before 5th Episode of season 6? If yes then when & how? Does that mean what we are watching right now is also the past and not the present and somewhere in the future there is a adult Bran? Which basically means all the previous 5 seasons and this season are actually all past events not present?

Also I have a theory that the "three eyed raven" is actually a fully grown adult Bran teaching his younger self.

This whole present past thing is very confusing. Its the "Back to the future" thing all over again.

Comment: Time travel and paradox. Interesting. Bran's tree thingy affected the young Hordor and that is why Hordor is Horder in the first place.

Comment: @NVZ but that means that the sequence of events that happened in the latest episode have already happened before hence Hordor being Hordor from season 1. Its all so confusing.

Comment: It's very common in The Flash. Spoilers ahead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrI7bxofcSQ

Comment: There are different kinds of **Time travel and paradox**.  One in which you go back to past change a few things and when you return back to your timeline everything would have been changed. In another scenario you time traveling is meant to be i.e your current timeline is the result of what you did by time traveling to past. In this case it is the latter.    </br> As per your theory, you can have whatever theory you want, just wait till the final season to confirm it all

Comment: If you haven't yet, I recommend watching ["Predestination"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2397535/). Absolute *mindfuck*.

Comment: No, the identity of the Three-eyed raven is [well-known](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers).

Comment: http://www.vox.com/2016/5/22/11722146/game-of-thrones-season-6-recap-hodor-dies-bran-time-travel

Comment: I posted then deleted an answer based on the Three Eyed Raven's line "The past is already written. The ink is dry" in episode 3. On second thoughts, we just don't know yet whether he was right or not. Right now, no characters know how it works in the show, so we can't be certain either. We don't even know where in time Bran is now. Maybe the raven didn't wake him because he's needed in the past more than he's needed in the present?

Comment: @BCdotWEB it doesn't help that the TER says "the time has come... for you [bran] to become me [TER]" in this episode.

Answer (score 7):

As per S06E05, it seems that time travel in Game of Thrones is following [Novikov self-consistency principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle).

> The Novikov self-consistency principle, named after Igor Dmitrievich
>   Novikov, states that any actions, taken by a time traveler or by an
>   object that travels back in time, were part of history all along, and
>   therefore it is impossible for the time traveler to "change" history
>   in any way. The time traveler's actions may be the cause of events in
>   their own past though, which leads to the potential for circular
>   causation, sometimes called a predestination paradox, ontological
>   paradox, or bootstap paradox. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel#Ontological_paradox)

So there is no butterfly effect in time travel in Game of throne as Time Travel is happened in past, so it's all in history itself.

But your theory about Three-eyed raven being Bran seems wrong, as we only see Bran being in past or seeing present through weirwood trees only and we haven't seen weirwood trees helping him see future yet or if they can even able to do that or not.

And as per  BCdotWEB's comment, in the books it is revealed that

> [Brynden Rivers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers) is three-eyed crow ( TV series changed the term crow to raven).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is not necessarily. As @pradyot brought up in his comment, "time travel" can have different effects on the present day situation depending on the laws of the universe in question. You can't think of the Game of Thrones time travel in the same way as Back to the Future, where each changed event creates a different timeline with different present day situations. In the GoT universe, there is one timeline in which everything that happened in the past has already happened, and if someone time travelled to cause certain events, they MUST complete those actions or paradox will occur.

Basically, Hodor has been Hodor since the time that Bran travelled back to. Whether Bran travelled back there in season 1, season 6, or when he's 80 years old doesn't matter. Hodor has been Hodor since Ned was a young kid because that's the time that Bran travelled to, and the time in the "present" has no effect on that beyond the fact that Hodor's traumatic death happened in the present while Bran was in the past and warging Hodor at the same time.

If this is still confusing, or I haven't done a good enough job of explaining, think about this:

Hodor has been Hodor since before Bran was born, so how would Bran travelling back in time in season 1 be any different than season 6? Bran had no chance to travel back before he was born obviously, so the effects of his time travel on the present day must hold true from the time he travels TO and not the time he travels FROM.

Comment: Is Hodor really dead? How can you confirm it? In the 5th Episode season 6 we just see him getting scratched and all but not really dead. Very much like the Hound, we dont know if these characters are still dead.

Comment: Can't confirm, just assumed. Fair point.

Comment: Or Stannis the menace.

Comment: Nah! Stannis is dead, Brienne confirmed it.