# Is Bran seeing the future?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

We know Bran from *Game of Thrones* can visit and even affect the past by his greenseeing abilities with the weirwood tree. However, he saw wildfire in a tunnel, which is the exact scene in which Cersei gets all her enemies burned during her trial in S06E10.

Does it mean he is also seeing the future?

Comment: can you get a screen grab on the vision you speak of, or at least which episode it appeared in?

Comment: @Skooba it was the beginning of season 6 episode 6, one of the many quick cuts was wildfire in a tunnel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visions and [prophecies](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/Prophecies/Entry/IV_540_541_Maggy_the_Frogs_Prophecy) in Game of Thrones so far have a tendency of playing out, and there is some crossover in Bran's visions to those that Daenerys has in the house of the undying.

Bran saw the past, the present and the future in all of his vision sequences:

- S04E02 - [The Lion and the Rose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdGy2.jpg)
- S06E06 - [Blood of my Blood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InY5G.jpg)

And Dany had, what seemed at the time, [more of a metaphorical vision](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gulVUWrADCM) but the evidence from Bran's more recent visions imply that, at least the snow/ash covered throne room, Dany's may also be more literal.  In fact, the only thing we don't already know is now in the past, from all of Bran's visions, are the ash/snow throne room 
[image]

and the shadow of a dragon over King's Landing

[image]

---

Alt Shift X has also [put out a video on Dany's visions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUIP7kWU8J0), but it shows how important visions are in the world of ASoIaF.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Bran did see the future in that scene in S06E06

But it seems more like a hint for viewers towards what's going to happen and what already happened. Like a way to give flashbacks and flashforwards.

We did see him [kind of changing the past](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/53393/1190), but his control seems a bit vague for now. So we can't be sure if he can specifically see the future with control or it's just going to be random like S06E06.

Comment: When did he change the past?

Comment: @Tom hold the door

Comment: @AnkitSharma It's important to note he can't actually change the past though, GoT seems to operate on a fixed timeline which means history is already written.

Comment: ` "The past is already written, the ink is dry"` -the three eyed raven.

Comment: @Tom but he also told Bran they couldn't see or hear him - there's something of a theme of people thinking they understand the mystic stuff then realising too late that they don't

Comment: @user568458 That doesn't mean the ink isn't dry. If he heard him that has already been written into history, Bran at that moment was always going to yell his name.

Comment: @Tom but that past was bran's present for that moment.

Comment: He didn't change the past, but instead "Hodar Paradox" helps confirm that  GOT is in some kind of "predetermined" universe where time must be a flat circle within cycle cosmology, which is then furthered by visions of future, which is also not just seen by Bran and possibly Dany in THotU, but also emphasized by Jojen Reed (about Greenseers) in season four when talking with Karl Tanner at Craster's Keep just before the raid.

Comment: The story relies on "no one" knowing everything, but characters coming to know whatever they know when they know it, which ties into their sealed fates, including how the books make a much bigger deal out of reincarnation, than the TV show does.