# Have we seen the bloodstained hand scene from Bran's vision?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I was watching a slo-mo video of Bran's visions [courtesy of this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56114/is-bran-seeing-the-future):

One of them goes like this (starting from 1:37 in that video):

1. Wildfire being poured
2. Aerys shouting "Burn them all!"
3. A wildfire explosion in a tunnel...
4. Wildfire being placed in the tunnel
5. Jaime drawing his sword and advancing on Aerys
6. A young Ned saying "Where's my sister"
7. A closeup of a bloodstained hand, opening and clenching its fingers. It appears to be someone's right hand, could be a man's or a burly woman's, wearing what looks like a leather sleeve with string, on some kind of stone or rough metal surface, with what looks like another more slender/feminine right hand touching the sleeve.

[image: Screenshot from the video, showing an open bloodstained hand]
[image: Screenshot from the video, showing a closed bloodstained hand]
<sub>(these are screenshots, click them for a larger version)</sub>

8. Jaime stabbing a fleeing Aerys
9. Robb not having a great time at Edmure's wedding
10. Jaime pulling his sword from Aerys' back
11. A black raven flying
12. Robb falling at the red wedding
13. A closeup of Leaf the child of the forest
14. A whitewalker swinging at Hardholme
15. Jaime making himself comfortable on the iron throne
16. More wildfire explosion, dragons, babies being turned into white walkers, and continuations of previous scenes

**What's the scene with the bloodied hand?** Have we seen it yet? [We know that some of these are scenes from the future](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56114/is-bran-seeing-the-future), I'm wondering if this is one too, or if it's simply something from existing footage that I'm failing to recognise.

At first I thought it might be Jaime losing his hand, which would slightly fit with the theme, but it doesn't make sense that the fingers clench *after* they are covered in blood? Or possibly a moment from the Red Wedding?

From the sequence of the video (and also this is what I thought when I first watched the scene) it could be from S06E10:

> Young Ned with Lyanna, clasping his bloodstained hand after trying to help her. What I thought was stone could be bloodstained sheets?

… but the positioning doesn't look right, the backdrop doesn't look right, and I don't recognise it or remember him making that clasping gesture.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Your edit moved the images out of the list again. Could you please revert it? (I can’t change it because of the min-length edit requirement - two spaces are not enough)

Comment: @unor True, but it also puts them next to each other, which profits conciseness and streamlining. But feel free to roll it back if you object to it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I can’t rollback (permission thing, I guess). If you want to keep it, could you please let the broken off list start at nr. 8 (by replacing "1." with "8.") and move the sub text "(these are screenshots, click them for a larger version)" out of the list, too? (again, can’t do it myself because these would only be 2 chars changed)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's from the full flashback scene where Ned discovers Lyanna in the Tower of Joy.
S06E10 at approx 55:17

We don't see that exact shot, but this is as close as we do see ...

[image]

Ned is kneeling by the bed, and reaches out to Lyanna's hand as she lifts it. The blood-stained wood you see is the bed frame.
It then cuts to a wider shot from overhead, which I've included to give some perspective to the scene.

[image]

We do see Ned's bloodied hand later [55:59]

[image]